# Oracle wrong number or types error

Tags: c#, oracle

Good morning everyone, I come for days trying to make this work but can not find the way. I get the following error

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong number or types 
                                          of arguments in call to 'ALTA_SOCIO'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I can not post images yet excuse me if it is not entirely clear

This is the code

```cs
   protected override void EjecutarConcreto()
    {
        int retornoNroSocio = (int)retorno.ObjetoGenerico;


        OracleParameter parameterNickname = new OracleParameter("p_nickname", OracleType.VarChar, 32767);
        parameterNickname.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterNickname.Value = nickname;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterNickname);

        OracleParameter parameterNombre = new OracleParameter("p_nombre", OracleType.VarChar, 32767);
        parameterNombre.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterNombre.Value = nombre;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterNombre);

        OracleParameter parameterApellido = new OracleParameter("p_apellido", OracleType.VarChar, 32767);
        parameterNombre.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterNombre.Value = apellido;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterApellido);


        OracleParameter parameterTipoDocumento = new OracleParameter("p_cod_tipo_documento", OracleType.VarChar, 32767);
        parameterTipoDocumento.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterTipoDocumento.Value = tipoDocumento;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterTipoDocumento);

        OracleParameter parameterNroDocumento = new OracleParameter("p_numero_documento", OracleType.Number);
        parameterNroDocumento.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterNroDocumento.Value = numeroDocumento;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterNroDocumento);

        OracleParameter parameterFechaNacimiento = new OracleParameter("p_fecha_nacimiento", OracleType.DateTime);
        parameterFechaNacimiento.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterFechaNacimiento.Value = fechaNacimiento;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterFechaNacimiento);

        OracleParameter parameterSexo = new OracleParameter("p_sexo", OracleType.VarChar, 32767);
        parameterSexo.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterSexo.Value = sexo;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSexo);

        OracleParameter parameterCodCategoria = new OracleParameter("p_cod_categoria", OracleType.VarChar, 32767);
        parameterCodCategoria.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterCodCategoria.Value = codCategoria;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterCodCategoria);


        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("p_numero_socio", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("p_codigo_error", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        //Ejecuto el comando
        ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is the table

```
  NUMERO_SOCIO                     NUMBER(7) NOT NULL,

  NICKNAME                         VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,

  APELLIDO                         VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,

  NOMBRE                           VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,

  COD_TIPO_DOCUMENTO               VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,

  NRO_DOCUMENTO                    NUMBER(8) NOT NULL,

  COD_CATEGORIA                    VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,

  FECHA_NACIMIENTO                 DATE,

  SEXO                             VARCHAR2(1)
```

and the procedure:

```
PROCEDURE alta_socio(
    p_nickname IN VARCHAR2,
    p_nombre IN VARCHAR2,
    p_apellido IN VARCHAR2,
    p_cod_tipo_documento IN VARCHAR2,
    p_numero_documento IN NUMBER,
    p_fecha_nacimiento IN DATE,
    p_sexo IN VARCHAR2,
    p_cod_categoria IN VARCHAR2,
    p_numero_socio OUT NUMBER,
    p_codigo_error OUT NUMBER);



  [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    public RetornoNroSocio AltaSocio(string codUsuario, string claveUsuario, string establecimiento, string nick, string nombre, string apellido, int documento, DateTime fechaNacimiento, char sexo, string codCategoria)
    {
        RetornoNroSocio rn = new RetornoNroSocio() { NroSocio = 0 };

        if (codUsuario != null && claveUsuario != null && establecimiento != null && nick != null && codUsuario != null && nombre != null && apellido != null && (sexo == 'M' || sexo == 'F') && codCategoria != null)
        {
            //Verifico que si el documento es una cedula sea valido
            if (PUtiles.CedulaUruguaya.validarCedula(documento.ToString()))//REVISAR ESTA VALIDACION
            {
                //Verifico que el usuario tenga permisos

                RetornoBool rb = new SeguridadAccesoClub().TienePermiso(codUsuario, claveUsuario, Globales.ACC_VERIFICAR_SOCIO, Globales.MODO_INGRESO);

                //En caso de que no ocurra ningun error y el usuario tenga permisos 
                if (!rb.Error && rb.Resultado)
                {
                    //Verifico que el usuario no exista
                    int NumeroSocioSiExiste = ValidarSocio(establecimiento, codUsuario, claveUsuario, Globales.CODIGO_DATOS_DNI, documento.ToString()).NroSocio;
                    if (NumeroSocioSiExiste == 0)
                    {

                        //Creo y realizo la peticion a la API
                        PeticionAPI p = new AltaSocio(establecimiento, nick, nombre, apellido, Globales.DOCUMENTO_CI, documento, fechaNacimiento, sexo, codCategoria);
                        RetornoGenerico r = p.Ejecutar();
                        if (!r.Error)//si no hay error
                        {
                            rn.Codigo = 0;
                            rn.Mensaje = "Socio creado OK";
                            rn.NroSocio = (int)r.ObjetoGenerico;//El numero de socio

                        }
                        else//si hay error
                        {
                            rn.Codigo = -99;
                            rn.Mensaje = "Se produjo un error inesperado ";
                            rn.NroSocio = 0;
                            var _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("log4Net");
                            _logger.Error("Error al dar de alta un usuario " + 
                                r.MensajeError + " Datos: CodUsuario: "+ codUsuario +" ClaveUsuario: "+ claveUsuario
                                +" Establecimiento: " + establecimiento + " Nick: " + nick + " Nombre: "+ nombre +
                                " Apellido " + apellido + " Documento: " + documento + " FechaNacimiento: "+ fechaNacimiento +
                                " Sexo: " + sexo + " CodCategoria: " + codCategoria);   
                        } 

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rn.Codigo = -1;
                        rn.Mensaje = "Este socio ya existe";
                        rn.NroSocio = NumeroSocioSiExiste;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    if (rb.Error)
                    {
                        rn.Codigo = -3;
                        rn.Mensaje = "Error al obtener los permisos del usuario";
                        rn.NroSocio = 0;
                        var _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("log4Net");
                        _logger.Error("rror al obtener los permisos del usuario " +
                            rb.MensajeError + " Datos: CodUsuario: " + codUsuario + " ClaveUsuario: " + claveUsuario
                            + " Establecimiento: " + establecimiento);   
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rn.Codigo = -4;
                        rn.Mensaje = "El usuario no tiene los permisos de acceso necesarios para realizar la consulta.";
                        rn.NroSocio = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                rn.Codigo = -2;
                rn.Mensaje = "Numero de cedula no es valido ";
                rn.NroSocio = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            rn.Codigo = -5;
            rn.Mensaje = "Alguno de los campos es vacio";
            rn.NroSocio = 0;
        }

        return rn;

    }
```

namespace WcfServicioAccesoCASClub.PConsumoAPIs {
    public abstract class PeticionAPI {

```
    private OracleConnection ora_conn;

    protected OracleCommand ora_cmd;
    protected string codEstablecimiento;
    protected string connectionString;
    protected string nombreProcedimiento;
    protected string nombreProcedimientoReal;
    protected CommandType tipoComando = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    protected RetornoGenerico retorno;

    public RetornoGenerico Ejecutar() {
        InicializarRetorno();

        try {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(codEstablecimiento)) {
                connectionString = ObtenerConnectionString(codEstablecimiento);

                RetornoGenerico rg = OperacionPrevia();
                if (!rg.Error) {
                    ora_conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);

                    ora_conn.Open();

                    CrearComando();

                    EjecutarConcreto();
                } else {
                    retorno.Error = true;
                    retorno.MensajeError = rg.MensajeError;
                }
            }else{
                retorno.Error = true;
                retorno.MensajeError = "No se recibio un establecimiento válido.";
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            retorno.Error = true;
            retorno.MensajeError = string.Format("Error al ejecutar el comando {0}. \nDescripcion del error: {1}", nombreProcedimiento, ex.Message);
        } finally {
            if (ora_conn != null && ora_conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) {
                ora_conn.Close();
            }
        }

        return retorno;
    }

    protected virtual RetornoGenerico OperacionPrevia() {
        return new RetornoGenerico() { Error = false, MensajeError = string.Empty, ObjetoGenerico = null };
    }

    protected void CrearComando() {
        ora_cmd = new OracleCommand(nombreProcedimiento, ora_conn);
        ora_cmd.CommandType = tipoComando;
    }

    protected abstract void EjecutarConcreto();
    protected abstract void InicializarRetorno();

    protected string ObtenerConnectionString(string codEstablecimientoIn) {
        return GeneradorConnectionString.Instance.ObtenerConnectionString(codEstablecimientoIn);
    }

    protected string MensajeError(int nroError) {
        string mensajeError = string.Empty;

        ora_cmd = null;
        ora_cmd = new OracleCommand("cj_boldt.utl_terminales.obtener_error", ora_conn);
        ora_cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        OracleParameter parameterNroSocio = new OracleParameter("p_codigo_error", OracleType.Number);
        parameterNroSocio.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterNroSocio.Value = nroError;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterNroSocio);
        OracleParameter parameterNombre = new OracleParameter("p_nombre_procedimiento", OracleType.VarChar, 32767);
        parameterNombre.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameterNombre.Value = nombreProcedimientoReal;
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterNombre);
        ora_cmd.Parameters.Add("p_mensaje_error", OracleType.VarChar, 32767).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        //Ejecuto el comando
        ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //Obtengo los valores recibidos por parametro  
        try {
            mensajeError = ora_cmd.Parameters["p_mensaje_error"].Value.ToString();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            mensajeError = "Ocurrio un error en la conexión";
        }

        return mensajeError;
    }

}
```

}

I appreciate any help thank you very much

Comment: Are you using stored procedure? If so, show its signature please (parameters) and also show ora_cmd syntax

Comment: Sorry here is
    PROCEDURE alta_socio(

        p_nickname IN VARCHAR2,
        p_nombre IN VARCHAR2,
        p_apellido IN VARCHAR2,
        p_cod_tipo_documento IN VARCHAR2,
        p_numero_documento IN NUMBER,
        p_fecha_nacimiento IN DATE,
        p_sexo IN VARCHAR2,
        p_cod_categoria IN VARCHAR2,
        p_numero_socio OUT NUMBER,
        p_codigo_error OUT NUMBER);

Comment: and please, all lines for ora_cmd that are executed before EjecutarConcreto call

Comment: Your code looks correct, the problem probably in usage of ora_cmd. You probably have more parameters in the actual call because some other parameters were added before (e.g. if you call this method twice). Do not forget to clear params before the new call. I will copy it to an answer so you can accept it if it helped :)

Comment: You can try omitting the parameter size for the VARCHAR parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Varchar lengths in stored proc and application code parameters are different. Set proper lengths
2. In general code looks correct, the problem probably in usage of ora_cmd. You probably have more parameters in the actual call because some other parameters were added before (e.g. if you call this method twice). Do not forget to clear params before the new call.

Comment: after your update i can see you clear parameters. So try option #1 and make sure your values lengths don't exceed proper sizes

Comment: @GabrielNuñez Let me know if it helped. Really interesting case.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try, I need a little more reputation to accept the answer .But  when I have it accept it. thank you very much

Comment: @GabrielNuñez i would look for a way to see what actually being sent to Ora server. Unfortunately i mostly work with MS SQL, not ORA but i'm sure there are tools that can monitor server requests, so try to find it. The alternative is to set a breakpoint on ora_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); and see what exact values or even SQL statement is sent to server.